# WMTS layer in Intramaps roam

Tags: qgis, python, intramaps-roam

I m currently trying to build app in the Intramaps roam. IntraMaps Roam is a simple data collection application built using QGIS. Roam is built as a standalone fully packaged Python application with everything included. QGIS is not required to be installed on the users machines. [see this url](http://roam-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) for more information.

At the moment I m trying to add a topo background layer. This backgroundlayer (brtachtergrondkaart) is a WMTS provided by the dutch gouverment and is open source. The url to this WMTS layer 
is: https://geodata.nationaalgeoregister.nl/tiles/service/wmts?request=GetCapabilities&service=WMTS

I have added the WMTS layer to the QGIS project that the app uses. When i start the app and open the map I get the following message: Failed to load brtachtergrondkaart.

I can't find in [the documentation of Intramaps roam](http://roam-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/admin-guide/projectadmin/) if a WMTS layer is supported. Does anybody know if this is integrated or do I have to make this feature in the program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently this project has an issue exactly open with that.
Maybe you should contribute information to this issue in the official repository.
The update for WMS issue is 7 days ago.

https://github.com/DMS-Aus/Roam/issues/314